# how to set columns for search datatables jquery

Tags: jquery, search, filter, datatables

how to set columns for search datatable jquery? i use datatables and my problem is filter multi columns.

i am trying filter all columns in DataTables but only last field send to server for filtering.

```
function searchRow(selector, formName) {
    var $formId = $('#' + formName + 'Form');
    var formData = new FormData( $formId[0] );
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        table.column(pair[0]).search(pair[1]);
    }
    table.ajax.reload();
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer on datatables.net

live example:
http://live.datatables.net/qadoxalu/5/edit

and in forum datatables.net :
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/159954#Comment_159954

to The name should not be used, the counter should be used.